# how to get cell outside tableview function?

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I want to get cell inside a function (outside tableview function). try like this but when it change to row 1, it crashed.

Here is my code so far:

```
func ValueChecker(cell: UITableViewCell){
    let subCellInt = Int(CustomUserDefaults.shared.getSubCellRow())!
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as! BankPaymentDetailsCell
    let mainMenuValue = CustomUserDefaults.shared.getSubCell()
    if(mainMenuValue=="00" || mainMenuValue=="01" || mainMenuValue=="02" || mainMenuValue=="03" || mainMenuValue=="04" || mainMenuValue=="05" || mainMenuValue=="06"){
        selectedRow = -1
        cell.ivExpand.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * CGFloat.pi) * 180.0)
    }else{
        cell.ivExpand.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * CGFloat.pi) / 180.0)
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

subCellInt is indexpath.row which I save locally.

If I change to this:

```
let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: subCellInt, section: 0)) as! BankPaymentDetailsCell
```

It only work to cell number 0 (first cell)  but crashed if cell number 1 and 2 (for cell count 3).

How to get cell outside tableview function?

Update:
i use this code to access tableview cell from outside tableview function:

```
func ValueChecker(cell: UITableViewCell){
    let subCellInt = Int(CustomUserDefaults.shared.getSubCellRow())!
    let cell : BankPaymentDetailsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BankPaymentDetailsCell") as! BankPaymentDetailsCell
    let mainMenuValue = CustomUserDefaults.shared.getSubCell()
    if(mainMenuValue=="00" || mainMenuValue=="01" || mainMenuValue=="02" || mainMenuValue=="03" || mainMenuValue=="04" || mainMenuValue=="05" || mainMenuValue=="06"){
        selectedRow = -1
        cell.ivExpand.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * CGFloat.pi) * 180.0)
    }else{
        cell.ivExpand.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * CGFloat.pi) / 180.0)
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

so far, it works. it can access cell from outside tableview function and it did not crash anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Table view cells are only accessible when there is a table view large enough that they are loaded.

Comment: I don't think so, because if i get tableview cell inside tableview function, it works with minimum 1 row

Comment: Yes, because the first cell is loaded by default even if it cannot be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access any random cell of tableview from outside.
But there is a way by which you can achieve this.
You can use
   let visibleCells = yourTableView.visibleCells
by this method you can get an array of visible cells and you can do whatever you want